# Query Access db based on current row

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm trying to query an access db to display additional rows based on the current row column data. Below is my code and db query.

```
<asp:ListView ID="RecentArtworkList" runat="server" DataSourceID="ArtworkDatabase2">
<ItemTemplate>
    <p class="text"><asp:Label ID="ArtworkSubject" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ArtworkSubject")%>' /></p>
</ItemTemplate>
```

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="ArtworkDatabase2" runat="server" DataFile="~/app-data/content.mdb"
SelectCommand="SELECT [ArtworkTagPhotography], [ArtworkSubject], [ArtworkTimestamp], [ArtworkImageID]
FROM [artwork] WHERE ArtworkTagPhotography='digital-photography'">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ArtworkTagPhotography" QueryStringField="id" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

The current row has 2 tags associated with it (ArtworkTagPhotography, ArtworkTagPersonal). I'd like to have the top 3 rows displayed based on those tags. Each row will have 2 different tags.

Comment: Are you only ever showing the top three and if so is the page designed to have three separate areas or could you use a gridview and make the grid look nice. There are a few ways to do it but an idea of your layout would be great.

Comment: Hey @indofraiser, yah only the top 3 rows but based on the current page tags. I'm using a ListView with the items on the sidebar. You can see the page below:

[Artwork Display Page](http://darvinkmanwah.com/artwork-display?id=summer-time-at-kitsilano-beach-vancouver#art-title)

What do you mean by the page having 3 separate areas?